# Kinect V2 (Arm/Hand Reading) to G-Code

Tags: arduino, motor, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, kinect

I am very new to this space and would greatly appreciate some clear guidance.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, Arduino Mega 2560+Shield, and Kinect v2 + PC USB cable adapter.

I am currently building the [BCN3D MOVEO](https://www.bcn3dtechnologies.com/en/bcn3d-moveo-the-future-of-learning/) with the following goal:

To take in the right or left arm/hand motion of a person via the Kinect V2 to then be used to control the BCN3D robotic arm's stepper motors.

Below is my rough idea of what I should do. I know building the robotic arm will not be a problem but I am very lost on what to do with it after that.

**So I would like to know how I can take the real-time XYZ data from a user's arm/hand seen by the Kinect and convert that into G-Code?**

[image: Game Plan]